# How to contact Yahoo to get information fixed

Tags: yahoo

I get 4 or 6 calls a day at my house because Yahoo is claiming my home number is part of a business. It’s a total gamut—from cheaper electric to small biz loans to corporate credit cards. I know it’s Yahoo because when I search Google for the house phone number, Yahoo Local displays the association (`local.yahoo.com`).

I've tried to contact Yahoo through their web forms but nothing is answered and nothing is fixed. I've sent feedback from the web page on the broken listing. I've also wrote to Yahoo at the well known addresses of [RFC 2142](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt), and the contact information listed in the WHOIS database. The WHOIS database must be correct per ICANN requirements, so I *know* Yahoo received it.

I have even tried to call them at the number listed in help: 1-800-318-0612. The keep me on hold for 10 or 20 minutes. Then they play a message that states "the call volume is high, go to help if you are cut off". Then they drop the call.

What is so broken with Yahoo? How does one contact Yahoo to have incorrect information fixed?

Comment: Set your number as a hotline number and make some money of it (if it’s not illegal where you live, of course). :)

Comment: Ping [Marissa Mayer on Twitter](https://twitter.com/marissamayer)?

Comment: Even worse, from what I can see in their Yahoo Local help, you can't report errors unless you're the business owner. The general public can't report errors. Maybe that's your ticket: "Claim" the business and have them call your number to verify. Of course, if it's already claimed you should contact the business and get them to change it. I wish I had better suggestions for you, because that sucks.